# NestJS - How to use .env variables in main app module file for database connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables, nestjs, dotenv

I am working on my first NestJS application, which was working fine with hardcoded database connecting string in `app.module.ts`.

But then as per our requirements, I had to pick the database config values from environment files. For that, I followed the configuration documentation on the nestjs documentation website - https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration

But the issue is that I need to use the .env variables inside the same file for database connection, which is failing.

Here is my original code that was working fine:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRoot(`mongodb+srv://myusername:mypassword@myhost.net?retryWrites=true&w=majority&db=dbname`, { useNewUrlParser: true, dbName: 'dbname' }),
    ProductModule,
    CategoryModule,
  ],
  controllers: [
    AppController,
    HealthCheckController,
  ],
  providers: [AppService, CustomLogger],
})
```

Now, I wanted to pick those DB values from .env files which are like `local.env`, `dev.env` etc. depending on the environment. Now, my this code is not working:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({ envFilePath: `${process.env.NODE_ENV}.env` }),
    MongooseModule.forRoot(`mongodb+srv://${ConfigModule.get('DB_USER')}:${ConfigModule.get('DB_PASS')}@myhost.net?retryWrites=true&w=majority&db=dbname`, { useNewUrlParser: true, dbName: 'dbname' }),
    ProductModule,
    CategoryModule,
  ],
  controllers: [
    AppController,
    HealthCheckController,
  ],
  providers: [AppService, CustomLogger],
})
```

Comment: ConfigModule.get
to be
this.configService.get<string>('database.host')

Answer (score 84, accepted):

**1. Keeping using ConfigModule**

You need to set `NODE_ENV` in npm scripts so that it can be used to load an env file based on the env.

```json
"scripts": {
  "start:local": "NODE_ENV=local npm run start"
  "start:dev": "NODE_ENV=dev npm run start"
}
```

Now you can just use the `ConfigModule`:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({ envFilePath: `${process.env.NODE_ENV}.env` }), 
MongooseModule.forRoot(`mongodb+srv://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASS}@myhost.net?retryWrites=true&w=majority&db=dbname`, { useNewUrlParser: true, dbName: 'dbname' })
    ...
})
```

**2. Using `dotenv`**

```bash
npm install dotenv
```

Add some scripts to your `package.json` to set what env you are in.

```json
"scripts": {
  ...
  "start:local": "NODE_ENV=local npm run start"
  "start:dev": "NODE_ENV=dev npm run start"
}
```

Import `dotenv` in `main.ts` file. Make sure you do it at the top of the file.

```js
require('dotenv').config({ path: `../${process.env.NODE_ENV}.env` });
```

**3. Using `env-cmd`**

You can use `env-cmd` npm package.

```bash
npm install env-cmd
```

And add some commands for different envs in `package.json`, for example:

```json
"scripts": {
  ...
  "start:local": "env-cmd -f local.env npm run start"
  "start:dev": "env-cmd -f dev.env npm run start"
}
...
```

---

Now you can use the env variables, for example:

```js
MongooseModule.forRoot(`mongodb+srv://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASS}@myhost.net?retryWrites=true&w=majority&db=dbname`, { useNewUrlParser: true, dbName: 'dbname' })
```

`process.env.MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING`

**Update:**

To overcome the env set command problem in different platforms, you can install `cross-env` package.

```
npm install -D cross-env
```

And update the scripts:

```js
"scripts": {
  "start:local": "cross-env NODE_ENV=local npm run start"
  "start:dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=dev npm run start"
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your first suggestion and it worked fine for me (the only thing was that the require('dotenv') line had to come before the import of AppModule). This solution is simple and quick :)

Comment: can you show me the main.ts and app module where you wrote this working code ?

Comment: you can just put the `require('dotenv').config({ path: `../${process.env.NODE_ENV}.env` });` at the top of your main.ts.

Comment: Nest config service already has 'dotenv' under the hood

Comment: I am facing an issue with this method then env file is not loading although NODE_ENV is set it can't read the env

Comment: I've got this error `'NODE_ENV' is not recognized as an internal or external command,`
the script:
```
    "start": "NODE_ENV=dev nest start",
    "start:dev": "NODE_ENV=dev nest start --watch",
```

Comment: Hi @AhmadDeel that's because the command was for linux. you may need cross-env package and use `cross-env NODE_ENV=dev nest start`

Comment: I'm using `SET NODE_ENV=prod&& node dist/main` in windows now. somehow there should be no space between `prod` and `&&`

Answer (score 113):

From Nestjs docs here - https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration

These steps worked for me with MySQL and TypeORM.

1. Install Nestjs config module - `npm i --save @nestjs/config`. It relies on dotenv
2. Create a `.env` file in your root folder and add your key/value pairs e.g. `DATABASE_USER=myusername`
3. Open app.module.ts and import the config module

```
    import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
```

4. Add below line to the imports section of `app.module.ts`. I added it a the first import. It will load the contents of the .env file automatically.

```
    ConfigModule.forRoot(),
```

5. Then you can begin to use the env variables as per the usual process.env.<variable_name> in the database config section e.g.

```
    process.env.DATABASE_USER
```

For more configuration of the ConfigModule, see the link above. You can use a custom file/path and set the module visible globally.

Comment: I tried to do this with the "@nestjs/dotenv" module but it did not work. Worked perfectly with "@nestjs/config". Thanks!

Comment: This IS what Nest.js documents recommend, and the paid Nest.js course.

However, as of mid 2022, this is not working.  I followed the steps in the documentation and course exactly, and I'm getting "client password must be a string".

I'm getting ConfigModule dependencies and then that error is thrown.

Comment: you can also juste call ConfigModule.forRoot() as a normal function outside import and ask for process.env data, thanks

Comment: @MichaelJay 

I ran into the same issue and I had to use the async initialization function:

```JwtModule.registerAsync({
      useFactory: async () => ({
        secretOrPrivateKey: process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY,
        signOptions: {
          expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRATION_TIME,
        },
      }),
    }),```

Comment: It seems that you have to run ConfigModule.forRoot() *before* referring to process.env.MY_VAR. This also means that you have to put the ConfigModule.forRoot() *before* any imports of modules that is in turn referring to process.env.MY_VAR. It is probably best to make sure to *not* put any references to such vars on the top level.

Answer (score 32):

```
MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
  imports: [ConfigModule],
  useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
    uri: configService.get<string>('MONGODB_URI'),
  }),
  inject: [ConfigService],
});
```

Comment: tanx, often forget to "inject: [Configervice ] :)

Comment: This is the correct way to do it. Assuming you want to run everything through the config module which can run validation on vars before they are passed in.

Answer (score 21):

By using nestjs/config package:

> npm install @nestjs/config

After installing the package, in the app module (app.module.ts file):

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';

@Module({
  imports: [ConfigModule.forRoot()],
})

export class AppModule {}
```

After that .env files can be accessed all over the app.
Suppose your .env file looks like this.

```
DB_USER=mohit
```

to access DB_USER variable use process.env.DB_USER

Comment: This does the job to get environment variables in runtime, but OP also wants to get environment variables while importing the module. With your solution, OP needs to load mongoose module asynchronously, as @Daniel pointed out.

Comment: Tried this. This does not load .env variables. And process.env can be used without even using ConfigModule

Comment: FYI - verify your .env file uses EQUALS and not COLON.  This is right`DB_USER=mohit` and this is wrong `DB_USER:mohit`. I did this twice already :D

Answer (score 11):

You need to use the `MongooseModule.forRootAsync(() => {...})` instead of `MongooseModule.forRoot(...)`

This makes MongooseModule wait for its IOC dependencies.

See: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb#async-configuration

Comment: I updated my code as you suggested. But now I'm getting error - `Nest cannot export a module that is not part of the currently processed module`. Here is what I updated - `MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        uri: 'mongodb+srv://db_username:db_pass@myhost.net?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
        options: { useNewUrlParser: true, dbName: 'dbname' },
      }),
      inject: [ConfigModule],
    }),`

Comment: fix the inject from `ConfigModule` to `ConfigService` (Follow the NestJS docs)

Answer (score 2):

To use NestJS configuration (dot-env) in the app.module.ts itself, use `MongooseModule.forRootAsync({})`. Here is my code.

```
  @Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: () => ({
        uri: process.env.CONNECTION_STRING,
      }),
    }),
    ConfigModule.forRoot(
      {
        isGlobal: true
      }
    )
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: it still gives me the same error.

Comment: One thing that I personally do, in my projects is, create a file env.ts, and export configuration from that file. Example:- `export const port = 8080`, then import it `import { port } from 'env'`. This should work without `forRootAsync` and should work with `forRoot` too. I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 1):

```
MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
  useFactory: () => ({
    uri: process.env.DB_CONNECTION
  }),
}),
ConfigModule.forRoot({isGlobal: true,}),
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

There is much simpler way, [that described in documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration#using-in-the-maints).
In `main.ts` file you need to access config service:

```
const configService = app.get(ConfigService);
```

And after that get access to environment variable:

```
const port = configService.get('PORT');
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone needs an answer on how to use .env vars inside a configuration.js file used when initializing ConfigModule here is a little workaround I found.
Otherwise it was not possible to use this defined environment vars inside the configuration.js.
The approach to handle this configuration in app.module.ts:

```
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config'
import { configuration } from '@darmas/mobile-de'

// ...
// hacky way to make it work
ConfigModule.forRoot(),
ConfigModule.forRoot({
    load: [configuration],
    isGlobal: true,
}),
```

The solution was to call ConfigModule.forRoot() twice: First to make env vars privatly available and second the real initialization with configuration.js this time with appropiatly filled env vars. Without this first step the env vars are not accessible.

Here is an example of used configuration.js:

```
import 'dotenv/config'

let configuration
const e = process.env

if (e.NODE_ENV && e.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    // local dev config
    configuration = {
        test: e.TEST,
        uri: 'http://localhost:2001/v1/api/'
    }
} else {
    // production config
    configuration = {
        test: e.TEST,
        uri: e.URI
    }
}

const func = () => configuration

export { func as configuration }
```